# Why does the compiler think this if statement is an expression?

Tags: kotlin

I have this method that compares sorted lists and tells you which items from list 1 are missing from list 2, and vice versa, in O(N) time:

```
fun <T : Comparable<T>> compareSortedLists(
        list1: Iterable<T>,
        list2: Iterable<T>,
        onlyInList1: MutableCollection<T>,
        onlyInList2: MutableCollection<T>) {
    val it1 = PeekingIterator(list1.iterator())
    val it2 = PeekingIterator(list2.iterator())
    while (it1.hasNext() && it2.hasNext()) {
        val comp = it1.peek().compareTo(it2.peek())
        if (comp < 0)       // <-- ERROR: type inference failure
            onlyInList1.add(it1.next())
        else if (comp > 0)
            onlyInList2.add(it2.next())
        else {
            it1.next()
            it2.next()      // <---- Error: type mismatch
        }
    }
    it1.forEachRemaining { onlyInList1.add(it) }
    it2.forEachRemaining { onlyInList2.add(it) }
}
```

The Kotlin compiler (1.2.41) in IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.4 gives me a compile-time error (as marked above). The error message says:

```
Type mismatch.
Required: Comparable<Boolean>!
Found: T!
```

But I didn't intend the `if` to be an expression. I meant it as a statement (EDIT: I mean an expression whose value is ignored, since all `if`s are actually expressions). If I convert the `if` to a `when` then it compiles ok:

```
        when {                // <-- Look, no error! ;-)
            comp < 0 ->
                onlyInList1.add(it1.next())
            comp > 0 ->
                onlyInList2.add(it2.next())
            else -> {
                it1.next()
                it2.next()
            }
        }
```

Why does it think the `if` is an expression? And, of all things, why does it think a `Comparable<Boolean>!` is required? Where's the context that requires such a type?

Comment: "Why does it think the `if` is an expression" - Because it IS an expression: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html. So is `when`.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Good point. I imagined it is treated as a "statement" in certain contexts, but you're right. So, what I should have asked is: why is the `if` expression not a `Unit` type? And conversely, why does a `when` expression compile without errors when the `if` expression doesn't?

Comment: Good question, I don't know the answer at the moment :)

Comment: Show the working `when` code, maybe?

Comment: It's clear that this is a compiler bug. For example, add `as Any` to one of the then-branches. 1. The error is now gone. 2. `as Any` is greyed out and marked as a "useless cast".

Comment: As for "why `Comparable<Boolean>` of all types": `MutableCollection::add` is of type `Boolean`; `Boolean` is a subtype of `Comparable<Boolean>`; `it2.next()` is of type `T` which is a `Comparable<T>`, so `T` is inferred to `Boolean`. It just shows what steps the constraint solver took before giving up.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: oh my, one-in-a-million chance that the bug actually is in the _compiler_? Never thought I'd see one :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Ever since languages got type inference by constraint solving, it became a plague :) I must have submitted a dozen to IntelliJ and Eclipse for Java already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a compiler bug. I reported it here:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/KT-24886

This is a minimal reproducer:

```
fun <T : Comparable<T>> test(a: Iterable<T>) {
    val x = if (booleanExpr1())
        booleanExpr2()
    else if (booleanExpr3())
        booleanExpr4()
    else {
        a.iterator().next()
    }
}

fun booleanExpr1() = true
fun booleanExpr2() = true
fun booleanExpr3() = true
fun booleanExpr4() = true
```

Note that the issue isn't at all with the "if expression not being treated as a statement", but with type inference itself. The compiler should have worked out a valid upper bound of all the then-branches, but failed.